# Tweepy StreamListener doesn't get number from form in Flask view

Tags: python, flask, tweepy

I am passing a number from an HTML form to a Flask view to control how many tweets I collect with a Tweepy listener.  However, the listener just keeps collecting forever, rather than stopping after the max value I passed.  If I set the max value manually, it works correctly.  How do I pass a number from a form to the listener?

```
@fetchtweet.route('/fetchtrainingtweets/', methods=["POST"])
def ttweets():
    ...
    number = request.form['number']

    class Listener(StreamListener):
        def __init__(self, api=None):
            self.api = api or API()
            self.n = 0
            self.m = number

        def on_data(self, data):
            ...
            if self.n >= self.m:
                return False
            ...
    ...
    stream = Stream(auth, listener())
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare a string to an int.  In Python 2, strings are always greater than numbers.

All input values in HTML, no matter what the type of the input, are strings.  So all the data Flask sees in the form data is strings.  You have to convert to a number yourself.

```
number = request.form.get('number', type=int)
```